# Warum kann man sagen: "Ist Abtreibung Mord?"?

Tags: article

> Ist Abtreibung Mord?

Warum gibt es in diesem Satz keine Artikel? Die Wörter sind doch zählbar.

Answer (score 13):

Nein, damit sind keine abzählbaren Begriffe gemeint. Abzählen könnte man die Morde, die z.B. Jack Unterweger begangen hat, oder die Morde, die in einem gewissen Zeitraum in einer bestimmten Region verübt wurden.

Hier geht es aber um die Tat *Mord,* die im Strafgesetzbuch beschrieben ist. Damit ist also eine Tätigkeits-Klasse gemeint, und davon gibt es nicht mehrere. Ähnliches gilt für Diebstahl, Einbruch usw. Ebenso ist auch mit *Abtreibung* keine konkrete Abtreibung gemeint, also nicht die Schwangerschaft der Irene K., die am 3. November abgebrochen wurde, und auch nicht die zählbaren Abtreibungen in einem bestimmten Gebiet innerhalb einer gewissen Zeitspanne, sondern auch hier ist *Abtreibung* als Handlungsmuster gemeint.

Beispiel:

- Ohne Artikel, weil das Wort hier als Bezeichnung einer Klasse von Tätigkeiten verwendet wird:

  > Wenn du etwas an dich nimmst, das dir nicht gehört, ist das **Diebstahl.**
- Mit Artikel, weil damit eine konkrete Tat gemeint ist:

  > Bekennen Sie sich schuldig, am 13. 8. gegen 16:30 Uhr **einen Diebstahl** begangen zu haben?

Im Plural kann man auch von mehreren konkreten Taten sprechen:

> In Wien wurden im September um 5,8% mehr **Diebstähle** begangen als im August.

Und genau dasselbe gilt auch für Mord und Abtreibung.

Comment: +1 vllt. könnte man noch ergänzen, dass der Artikel setzbar ist. (..., ist das (ein) Diebstahl)

Comment: Oder wie die Scholastiker sagen würden: [suppositio simplex vs. suppositio personalis](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ockham/#SignConnSupp).

Comment: Soll das nicht "begangen" sein?

Answer (score 9):

> Ist Abtreibung Mord?

In dieser Frage geht es offenbar ganz allgemein um die abstrakten Ideen *Abtreibung* und *Mord*. Die Ideen sind nicht abzählbar, daher werden die beiden Wörter artikellos gebraucht. Das ist auch in anderen Sprachen, wie dem Englischen, so:

> Is abortion homicide?

Wenn es um konkrete Abtreibungen und konkrete Mordhandlungen geht, erkennt man das in der Regel an der Verwendung von Artikeln:

> War *die* späte Abtreibung ihres Ungeborenen *der* besagte Mord?
>
> (Was *the* late abortion of her unborn child *the* very homicide?)